# Google Structured Data Delegation

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, google-knowledge-graph

I am attempting to get events to show up in the Google Knowledge panel for a business. I have created an organization SD JSON object in the header of the business homepage and delegated the events to another website with proper event markup (microdata) on the page.

I used the following documentation
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/events#delegation_markup

I have had Google reindex the page and the structured data object shows up in the cached version of the website. I have also waited 3 days before posting here to ensure it had time to get captured by Google and related in searches.

I would like to know if there is something wrong with the following markup, etc in order to get the delegated events to show up in the Google Knowledge panel.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context":"http://schema.org",
"@type":"Organization",
"legalName":"Diversified Design and Manufacturing",
"address":"165 Boro Line Road, King of Prussia, PA 19406",
"email":"www.diversifieddesignmfg.com/",
"telephone":"(610) 337-1969",
"event": "http://www.burbio.com/groups/diversified-design-and-manufacturing"
}
```

Also I noticed most release notes and documentation refers to MusicGroups, etc. Is event delegation supported for Organization type SD objects?

Answer (score 0):

Google provides the following information for [trouble-shooting events:](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings#troubleshooting-events-in-knowledge-graph-cards)

**Troubleshooting events in Knowledge Graph cards** 
Knowledge Graph card display is governed by a complex algorithm, so if you don’t see your artist or your artist’s events in the Knowledge Graph card, try these steps:

- Make sure that the artist is in both Wikipedia and MusicBrainz, and that the artist's official home page is recorded properly on both those sites.
- For events missing from a Knowledge Graph card, check that the events
  are shown correctly with no errors in the Structured Data Testing
  Tool.

If all fields look correct, report the missing events using the Feedback link under the Knowledge Graph card in Google search.
   Please report it asgeneral feedback and be sure to use the  term events in your description of the problem.

It also states that event information should come from the *ticket seller's website** and that **you cannot use delegation to link to your own website**.

SOLUTION -
Firstly, it appears only certain artists are expected to appear in Knowledge Graph Events.

Secondly, your structured data does not contain any information about the specific event, eg start or end time, location or name. The `event` field must be of type `http://schema.org/Event` OR a hyperlink to a webpage with `http://schema.org/Event` markup - the link you included does not refer to any specific event.

If the destination does not contain `http://schema.org/Event` structured data you can include it manually by nesting it inside `http://schema.org/Organization` (not delegate) event data inside the Organization as follows:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
"@context":"http://schema.org",
"@type":"Organization",
"legalName":"Diversified Design and Manufacturing",
"address":"165 Boro Line Road, King of Prussia, PA 19406",
"email":"www.diversifieddesignmfg.com/",
"telephone":"(610) 337-1969",
"event": {
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Event",
  "name": "Chinese New Year Festival",
  "url": "http://chinesenewyear-2017.org/festival"
  "startDate": "2016-01-28T06:00",
  "description": "The best Chinese New Year party in 2017",
  "location": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "name": "Missoula, MT",
    "url": "http://www.missoula.com/",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "addressLocality": "Missoula",
      "addressRegion": "MT"
    },
 }
}
```

Google requires certain fields to be included, such as `startDate`, `Location`, see at the bottom of [this page](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/events) from google's documentation

Finally, in your example code the `email` field contains a website URL - not an email address.